# Java program w/JNA+DLL requires "Run as Administrator" under C:\Program Files on Win10?

Tags: java, windows, dll, windows-10, jna

I have a Java 8 program which runs fine everywhere on my Windows 10 computer **except** when run from under C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86) where it requires to be "Run as Adminstrator" to work.

What are the limitations for running Java programs and accessing hardware from C:\Program Files ?

This Java program uses JNA to load a DLL and JavaFX to display a UI, so possibly that is related. A companion program in the same directory using on JavaFX but **NOT** JNA and DLLs works fine everywhere.

This is not an installer issue as an installer is not involved; the behavior does not change when an installer is used.

It is not an issue with embedded paths or with the 
(x86) and/or spaces in the path, as similar named directories to C:\Program Files (x86) also work fine.

Comment: If you want more than wild guesses, you're going to need to tell us what actually goes wrong when you run the program without elevation.  Assuming that the program starts up but then fails, the most common cause is that the program is trying to write into the directory it is being run from.

Comment: It fails in a custom library call which is difficult to debug, but I think that library is trying to write a file like Alex suggests below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that the issue is Java-related, it is more about OS security model. Note that you can't save file directly to both of these folders, for example, but can copy any file to that folder using elevated prompt. That is a good security practice, and in a past it could be turned off (as far as i remember) by turning off the UAC (which was not recommended, anyway).

If you want to update your application on a future then place it somewhere in different place as many apps doing.

Comment: That may actually be it; I'll check into it. But does that mean that once a program is installed it cannot update it's components stored in the program files directory? That any such components must be elsewhere like in Apps?

Comment: @user1663987: if you want to automatically update, without prompting the user for admin credentials, typically either you install the program somewhere else (e.g.,Google Chrome installs itself into the user's Application Data folder) or you install a system service to perform the update on your behalf.

Comment: Exactly as Harry said. Thanks you Harry. I updated the answer with that.

Comment: @user1663987 did you check the issue?